# I have an issue with includePath

Tags: c++

I have an error with inlcudePath here is what it says.

#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit
I also use Linux if that makes any difference

Here is my code

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "header.h"
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
```

Comment: The error is on the #include "header.h"

Comment: What environment (IDE, editor) are you using?

Comment: did you update your includePath? What is your includePath? Where is header.h located?

Comment: I use vscode, how do i update includePath?

Comment: Oh my goodness after hours the error finally said it had a quickfix that put this into my includePath     /usr/include/sound/sof

Comment: Have you read e.g. [this guide about VSCode with GCC on Linux](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux)? You need to edit two configuration files, one for VSCode and the C++ plugin to work, and one to build. Both needs to tell about the include paths.

Comment: I also recommend you read [What is the difference between #include <filename> and #include "filename"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename).

Comment: For future questions please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). That will help you write better questions, which makes it easier for us to actually help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, I put this into my Include Path

/usr/include/sound/sof

Comment: Do that library really have a header file named `header.h`? With the code you show it seems like you try to include your own custom header file. Does that `header.h` include some other header files? The point of a [mre] is that it should try to replicate the error you get, and if we don't have the actual code leading to the errors then it's really hard to help you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).